# Opening videos onItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying to open videos when the user clicks on an item from a list. I have the code for the listview working, and the code to open videos. I just can't figure out how to combine the two.

Here's my code to open videos.

```
    String video_path = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrEUBl2pacU";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(video_path);

    uri = Uri.parse("vnd.youtube: " + uri.getQueryParameter("v"));

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Is it possible to put this code into onItemClick?

Edit: Here's the whole class. I have a feeling that my code is incorrect, as it's all in onCreate. But, I followed a tutorial, and that's where is was.

```
public class Videos extends Activity{

private ListView lv;
String videoNames[] = {"Doctor Who Trailer", "T+S - Northshore", "Foo Fighters - Everlong"};

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.videos);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView);

    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, videoNames));
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>Videos, View v, int position, long id) {


    String video_path = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrEUBl2pacU";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(video_path);

    uri = Uri.parse("vnd.youtube: " + uri.getQueryParameter("v"));

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
};
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: I do not really understand what you actually wanna do. For question _Is it possible to put this code into onItemClick?_ answer is: _sure you can_.

Comment: When I put that code into onItemClick, my app crashes. I might be missing something completely obvious.

Comment: Put it in onItemClick and post the LogCat from the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your onclicklistener should look like. Try this code:

```
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_view,listItems);
    setListAdapter(aa);

    //This creates a listener for the Files listed
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String url = aa.getItem(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);   
            return false;
        }
    });
```

UPDATE: I would suggest using a Hashmap for a key value pair. Something like (I didn't compile this):

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("videoText1", "youtube_link1");
hm.put("videoText2", "youtube_link2");
hm.put("videoText3", "youtube_link3");
```

You then could get all of listview set by using hm.keySet().

```
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>(hm.keySet());
final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_view,listItems);
    setListAdapter(aa);
```

Lastly use the Hashmap to lookup the youtube link:

```
String url = hm.get(aa.getItem(position));
```

....

Comment: that worked! Thank you very much, you legend. The only problem is the items in my list view are now youtube links. Is there anyway to change that?

Comment: If solution worked you should mark this answer as right answer.

Comment: Yes I would agree with neworld. (:

Comment: I didn't end up using this code. I went back to my previous method and all worked correctly with a bit of tweaking. So I am not 100% sure if knennigtri's answer worked.